Equation tags in margin
Other tex.SE posts such as this one or this other concern allowing long equations and their tags to invade the margin, but this is not what I am trying to achieve. What I would like is to modify the position of all tags so that they appear on the right margin of the document, indifferently of the equation length, while equations themselves (that is, excluding the tag) remain centered w.r.t. to the body of the text.
The idea is to address three problems:

It is sometimes the case that equations are narrower than the text width, but wide enough as to displace the tag, which is ugly. This becomes more probable for larger tags, which typically appear in longer documents such as books if we choose to number within sections.
If only for such equations the tag was placed outside the text block, the document layout would loose homogeneity, which is ugly too.
If one employs \everydisplay as in this post, the equation itself (not the equation plus its tag) becomes visibly misaligned with the center of the body of the text, because latex centers the equation plus its tag. Moreover, setting displayindent causes errors with environments such as align.

That being said, however, I have no clue about how could one achieve this.

You first have to separate making tags and equation referencing, that unfortunately use the same \tagform@ macro.
Then you can redefine \tagform@ to push the tag in the margin. The width of the box ought to be positive, so I make it the smallest positive width possible, that is, 1sp.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum} % filler text

\makeatletter
% detach \eqref and \tag making
\renewcommand{\eqref}[1]{\textup{\eqreftagform@{\ref{#1}}}}
\let\eqreftagform@\tagform@
\def\tagform@#1{%
  \maketag@@@{\makebox[1sp][l]{\hspace{3em}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\kant[1][1-2]
\begin{equation}\label{first}
A+A=2A
\end{equation}
\kant[2][1-2]
\begin{align}
A &= thisisaveryveryveryverylongequationthatwillalmosttouchthemargin \\
B &= shorterequation
\end{align}
We end with references: \eqref{first}.

\end{document}


